# how to grab alternating child tags in python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a series of data from alternating tags in a html page.
The html looks like this:

```html
<div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <div>text</div>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <div>text</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Since I can't grab each h3/div pair in a "for each pair in div", how to I grab them efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all headers, and grab the [next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) from there:

```
for header in soup.select('div h3'):
    next_div = header.find_next_sibling('div')
```

`element.find_next_sibling()` returns an element or `None` if no such sibling can be found.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <div>
...     <h3>First header</h3>
...     <div>First div to go with a header</div>
...     <h3>Second header</h3>
...     <div>Second div to go with a header</div>
... </div>
... ''')
>>> for header in soup.select('div h3'):
...     next_div = header.find_next_sibling('div')
...     print(header.text, next_div.text)
... 
First header First div to go with a header
Second header Second div to go with a header
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this, but the easiest for me would be to select all the `h3` tags and then walk the DOM to get their next sibling.